# Problema con el cursor de texto en el campo de formulario al usar @keyframe

Tags: html, css

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Restaurante El mediterraneo - Contactenos</title>
</head>
<body>
        <header class="cabecera">
            <div class="container">
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <section id="banner" class="banner-contacto">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="fila fila-centrada">
                        <div class="columna columna-50">
                            <h1 class="centrar-texto">Contáctanos</h1>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="flecha">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i>
                </a>
            </section>
            <section id="contacto" class="seccion">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="fila">
                        <div class="columna columna-50">
                            <form id="formcontacto" action="registro.php" method="post">
                                <div class="form-bloques">
                                    <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-bloques">
                                    <input class="form-input" type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-bloques">
                                    <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="Asunto" name="asunto" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-bloques">
                                    <textarea class="form-input" required name="mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-bloques form-bloque-boton">
                                    <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" class="btn boton-amarillo">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </div>              
            </section>
        </main>
        <footer>
</footer>
    </body>
</html> el problema que he creado una clase flecha que estare posicionada en la seccion banner estara centrada y le di una animacion que es de arriba hacia abajo usando el siguiente propiedad @keyframes saltar{0%{bottom:3rem;},50%{bottom:5rem;},100{bottom:3rem;}}, y tambien le he dado estos estilos a la clase flecha
```

.flecha{width: 2.5rem;height: 2.5rem;border-radius: 100%;border: 0.2rem solid #FFF;color: #FFF;text-decoration: none;display: flex;font-size: 1.8rem;align-items: center;justify-content: center;position: absolute;bottom: 3rem;left: 50%;transform: translateX(-50%);animation-name: saltar;animation-duration: 1s;animation-timing-function: linear;animation-iteration-count: infinite;}
.flecha:hover
{animation-play-state: paused;} tambien he cerado otro html solo de prueba y tambien se ve reflejado ese problema que cuando le pongo una animacion a la flecha cuando coloco el mouse encima del campo de texto del formulario desaparece o se vuelve como invisible y mi duda si ya es tema del navegador porque en mozilla no pasa este problema me podrian ayudar a resolver este problema gracias

Comment: he identificado que al usar @keyframe es lo que me esta afectando porque al quitar la animacion todo funciona correctamente y al aplicar la animacion de nuevo persiste el problema

Comment: Muestra un [repro]. Es difícil saber qué está sucediendo si no muestras código. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: .flecha{le he dado priopiedades}
.flecha:hover{-webkit-animation-play-state:paused;animation-play-state:paused;}
@-webkit-keyframes saltar{0%{bottom:3rem;}
50%{bottom:5rem;}
100%{bottom:3rem;}
}
@keyframes saltar{0%{bottom:3rem;}
50%{bottom:5rem;}
100%{bottom:3rem;}
}

Comment: este es parte del codigo css de mi pagina web en la seccion contactos creo un<a> con clase flecha que es una flecha que va estar posicionada en la seccion contactos y le di una animacion que este como brincando para que al darle clik en la flecha baje hacia donde esta el formulario pero solo pasa en chrome y edge el problema radica en que al momento de poner el cursor encima del campo de texto del formulario este desaparece o no se ve pero solo pasa al momento de ponerlo encima del campo de texto y si elimino la animacion ya no pasa ese problema y en mozilla funciona con o sin animacion

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para agregar más detalles a tu pregunta. Los comentarios son efímeros, y, como verás, el código es ilegible aquí.

Comment: De hecho, al ser HTML + CSS, puedes crear un [repro] ejecutable en la pregunta a través de un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`), para visualizar en tu pregunta misma el inconveniente.